# Yii2: How to assign an id to each checkbox in checkboxList()

Tags: php, yii, yii2, checkboxlist

I have a [checkboxList](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-html#input-fields) created with Yii2 and I need to assign an id to each checkbox (so then I can use it with jQuery). But I don't know how to do it.

```
<?
$cities ArrayHelper::map(Cities::find()->all(), 'city_id', 'city_name');
echo Html::checkboxList(
    'cities'
    null,
    $cities,
    [
        'itemOptions' => [
            'id' => $cities->city_id // MY PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE,
        ],
    ]
) ?>
```

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: You are assigning 'city_id' as id

Comment: `$cities` is not an object. It's an array. You didn't assign mapped value to `$cities` variable, Missing `=`.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the docs [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#checkboxList()-detail), you can pass to `$options`'s (4th argument of `yii\helpers\Html::checkboxList`) `item` key an anonymous function where you can explicitly specify the HTML rendering structure to your checkbox list like this:

```
<?= Html::checkboxList('cities', null, $cities, [
        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) use ($cities) {
            return "<label class='checkbox col-md-4'>
                        <input type='checkbox' 
                               {$checked} 
                               name='{$name}'
                               value='{$value}' 
                               id='" . $cities[$index]->city_id . "'>
                        {$label}
                   </label>";
        }
    ]);
?>
```

Comment: You can also use `Html::label()` and `Html::checkbox()` methods  to generate the html code inside the item callback instead of writing the html code by yourself.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$cities ArrayHelper::map(Cities::find()->all(), 'city_id', 'city_name');
echo Html::checkboxList(
    'cities'
    null,
    $cities,
    [
        'itemOptions' => [
            'id' => $cities->city_id // MY PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE,
        ],
    ]
) ?>
```

should be

```
<?= Html::checkboxList('cities', null, ArrayHelper::map(Cities::find()->all(), 'city_id', 'city_name')) ?>
```

Comment: this should work, check if `ArrayHelper::map(Cities::find()->all(), 'city_id', 'city_name');` is returning id, name

Comment: @flakerimi I guess he wants to assign city_id as `id` attribute to the checkboxes.